# React useContext is undefined in useeffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, websocket, channel

I am coding a chat app with django channels and react. I want when a new message is send, to have a className of the current user.

I already have the current user in context so I just have to call it and get it. But when I try to get the user in useEffect, it returns {}.

```
const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext)
useEffect(()=> {
        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(currentUser)
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            setMessages(old => [...old, <p ref={oneRef} className={currentUser[0]?.username}>{data.message}</p>])
        };  
    },[])
```

Also I need the `useEffect` so I can't just remove it. I don't wanna to call an `axios` call every time a new message is sended. And the `currentUser` is an object.

Comment: But what if it really is undefined? ... docs https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#i-am-always-getting-undefined-from-my-context-although-the-default-value-is-different

Comment: It's not cause when I print it outiside of the useEffect I get it.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I try to get the user in useEffect, it returns undefined.

Haven't you just forgot to include `currentUser` in the *dependecy array*?

```
const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
const ref = useRef(false);

useEffect(()=> {
    if (!ref.current) return;

    if (currentUser) {
       ref.current = true;

       chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
          console.log(currentUser)
          const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
          setMessages(old => [...old, <p ref={oneRef} className={currentUser[0]?.username}>{data.message}</p>])
       };  
    }
}, [currentUser])
```

Comment: and the messages too?

Comment: @AmrKhaled Why? The `message` is declared and available inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: because I think this might cause an error for a missing dependency which will ned to be added.

Comment: @AmrKhaled Mhm, rather a `warning` since missing dependencies never throw an `error`. Anyways would be great to have some feedback from the asker though.

Comment: @kinduser Thanks for the answer now I currentUser object but now 2  messages are send at a time.

Comment: @kinduser Also only on the second one the className changes.

Comment: @zequuee1 Updated answer. Just implement the flag to call the messages only once, when `currentUser` is not undefined.

Comment: @kinduser I did it but now no messages are added.

Comment: @zequuee1 Does it log the currentUser?

Comment: It doesnt log the user.

Comment: @zequuee1 What then?

Comment: Oh wait I solved it with a cleanup function.

Answer (score 0):

As kinduser said I just added `currentUser` as dependacy. And because the messages were duplicated I solved it with a cleanup function. So now the code looks like this.

```
useEffect(()=> {
        let ran = true;
        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            if (ran == true) {
                console.log(checker) 
                const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                setMessages(old => [...old, <p ref={oneRef} className={currentUser[0]?.username}>{data.message}</p>])
                setChecker(false)
            }
        }

        return () => {
            ran = false;
        };
        
        
    },[currentUser])
```